# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS and Snappy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know anything about ROS and ubuntu Snappy? I remeber reading somewhere that they were developing a version of ROS to work with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205253/ros-and-snappy/) by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-18**:
Related articles:

- [Ubuntu ROS apps on the way](http://www.osrfoundation.org/ubuntu-ros-apps-on-the-way/)
- [Snappy package for Robot Operating System tutorial](http://www.piware.de/2015/01/snappy-package-for-robot-operating-system-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No need for a special version of ROS! [Snapcraft](http://snapcraft.io/) (the official build tool to make snaps) supports building ROS systems out of the box. Here's a [quick walkthrough](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docs/ros-snap.md).

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0